# Cycles Render is showing black silhouette

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm running into the attached issue when trying to render my model. I'm fairly new to blender and am using a free model form the internet to practice on. I'm not sure what is going on here.

I've done some googling prior to submitting this and none of the solutions I found resolved my issue.

https://imgur.com/vpirao5

Answer (score -2):

I found out the issue. I had some masks turned on...

Comment: It is great you found the solution, but could you elaborate on your answer so that others in similar situations could learn?